# F distribution: $P\{S_1\geq 3S_2\}$ with $n_1 = 7, n_2 = 13$

Tags: probability

Using the $F$ distribution table:
I think it should be $ P\{\frac{S_1}{S_2} \geq3\} = 1 - P\{\frac{S_1}{S_2} \leq 3\} = 1 - 0.05 = 0.95$. But my notes say it should be  $0.05$?

Comment: The mistake is saying that P{S1/S2<=3} = 0.05 as the given answers show it is close to 0.95.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X = \frac{S_1}{S_2}$ be F-distributed random variable. Then
$$
    f_X(x) = \frac{1}{B\left(\frac{n_1}{2}, \frac{n_2}{2}\right)} \frac{n_1}{n_2} \left( \frac{n_1 x}{n_2} \right)^{\frac{n_1}{2} -1} \left( 1 + \frac{n_1 x}{n_2} \right)^{-\frac{n_1+n_2}{2}}
$$
and
$$
     \mathbb{P}\left( X \geqslant 3 \right) = \int_3^\infty f_X(x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
The plot of $f_X(x)$ for given parameters looks as follows:

[image]

Clearly the probability $\mathbb{P}(X \geqslant 3)$ is small (it is the orange area in the plot). Using quadratures it equals $0.04156$.

Comment: The value of an F-distributed random variable is typically near $1$, so the probability that it's near $3$ will be fairly large.  (The exact mean and median depend on $n_1$ and $n_2$.)

Comment: Thanks, I was interpreting wrongly the $\alpha$ in the graph, now I know it measures the area to the right from $F = 3$.